# After earning a Master's degree, does one have reached the Master level?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, legalese, translation

I am translating a typical French diploma into English. The translation will be certified, so I am trying to use the proper terms.

The diploma reads `Le diplôme [...] confère le grade de Master.`, which means that by receiving the diploma, I have obtained the `Master level/rank`. What's the correct way to formulate it?

[image]

I would point out that in French we [draw a distinction](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_d&page=9EbjHmU9o4Lk.html) between the diploma (*diplôme*), the title (*titre*), and the level/rank (*grade*):

- diploma (*diplôme*) is the piece of paper
- title (*titre*) is the name one can use, e.g., Dr.
- level/rank (*grade*) is the academic level/rank a student have reached.

Comment: In the US and UK education systems, graduating from college is Bachelor (BS - Bachelor of Science, BA - Bachelor of Arts) degree, then Masters degree (MS - Master of Science,  MA - Master of Arts), then Doctorate of Philosophy (PhD). Is Masters in France and Masters in US/UK equivalent or is your Masters more similar to PhD?

Comment: @Peter Masters in France as similar to Masters in US and UK. Maybe degree would fit in hindsight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A student will **attain** a Masters degree.

> He **attained** a Masters degree at Harvard.
>   She **achieved** an MBA degree at HBS.
>   He **obtained** a Masters at Harvard.
>   He **received** the degree of Master of Arts in Impressionist Painting.

A school will **confer** a Masters degree.

There is no title specific honorary given for receiving a Masters as there is with a PhD (Dr.)

Comment: I've seen people addressed/described as a "Master of Arts" but this is definitely infrequent and not a recognised title or honorific in general use, this answer describes all the usual ways of expressing it: "has a masters degree" in most cases, or if talking about the course that confers the degree, usually the singular "while undertaking a Master *of*  Public Policy degree" — but this is just as often expressed as "while studying a Masters *in* Public Policy". I intuitively feel that the latter is less formal.

Comment: @Toadfish Yes, *technically* someone who has earned a BA **is** a Bachelor of Arts, someone who had earned a JD **is** a Juris Doctor, someone who has earned a PhD **is** a Doctor of Philosophy, and so on. These titles are virtually never used, with the exception of doctorates conferring the title of "Doctor" (depending on the degree and who you ask). Roughly: MDs always go by "Doctor", JDs never go by "Doctor" (they go by "Esquire" if they have passed the Bar Exam), and PhDs sometimes go by "Doctor".

Comment: In hospital situations, PhD's are asked not to use "Doctor" for obvious reasons.